# Use a Hive Registered UDF in Spark

Tags: hive, apache-spark-sql

I register a udf in Hive through beeline using the following:

```
CREATE FUNCTION udfTest AS 'my.udf.SimpleUDF' USING JAR 'hdfs://hostname/pathToMyJar.jar'
```

Then I can use it in beeline as follows:

```
SELECT udfTest(name) from myTable;
```

Which returns the expected result.

I then launch a spark-shell and run the following

```
sqlContext.sql("SELECT udfTest(name) from myTable")
```

Which fails. The stack is several hundred lines long (which I can't paste here) but the key parts are:

- org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$TranslatingClassLoader cannot be cast to java.net.URLClassLoader
- Unable to load resources for default.udftest:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to register [/tmp/blarg/pathToMyJar.jar]

I can provide more detail if anything stands out.

Is it possible to use UDFs Registered through Hive in Spark?

Spark Version 1.3.0

Answer (score 0):

When using a custom UDF, make sure that the jar file for your UDF is included with your application, **OR** use the --jars command-line option to specify the UDF-file as a parameter while launching spark-shell as shown below

```
./bin/spark-shell --jars <path-to-your-hive-udf>.jar
```

For more details refer [Calling Hive User-Defined Functions from Spark](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.4.0/bk_spark-guide/content/calling-udfs.html).

Comment: This requires knowing the classpath inside the jar to the actual UDF class when running the spark-shell. This is something I will not know at application run time. Is there any other way besides this?

Comment: You can copy the UDF Jar to some directory/path in HDFS yourselves and then give the path to spark-shell as you will know it.

Answer (score 0):

we had the same issue recently. What we noticed was that if the jar path is available locally then all goes through fine. and if the jar path is on hdfs , it doesnt work. So what we ended up doing was copying the jar locally using FileSystem.copytoLocalFile and then adding the copied file. Worked for us in cluster and client mode

PS. this is Spark 2.0 Im talking about